# WooCommerce get return url from browser url

Tags: woocommerce

```
// Save return URL to WooCommerce session before placing the order
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_process', 'save_return_url_to_session');

function save_return_url_to_session() {
    // Get the return URL from the query string
    $return_url = esc_url_raw($_GET['return_url']);

    // If the return URL is not empty, save it to the WooCommerce session
    if (!empty($return_url)) {
        WC()->session->set('return_url', $return_url);
    }
}
```

Before place order I see in browser:

```
https://website.com/order/?session_id=t_de802a80057524456efc9c2c20fde2&return_url=https://newpage.com/checkout
```

But still this  code "not see this return url".

Any solution? I use custom checkout plugin, so maybe it can be issue why this code not see this url browser? I checked and this hooks work directly in this checkout, but not possible get this return url from params.

Finally I try redirect to custom checkout page:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase');

function woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
    // Check if it's a valid order ID
    if (is_checkout()) {
        // Get the order ID
        $order_id = absint(get_query_var('order-received'));

        // If order ID is valid, add it to the return URL
        if (!empty($order_id)) {
            // Get the order object
            $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

            // Retrieve the return URL from the WooCommerce session
            $return_url_from_session = WC()->session->get('return_url');

            // If the return URL from the session is not empty, add the order ID to the end
            if (!empty($return_url_from_session)) {
                // Adjusted to use trailing slash in the URL structure
                $redirect_url = untrailingslashit($return_url_from_session) . '/' . $order_id;

                // Redirect to the modified URL
                wp_redirect($redirect_url);
                exit;
            } else {
                // If return URL is empty, redirect to the default URL
                $default_url = 'http://localhost:3000/checkout/' . $order_id;
                wp_redirect($default_url);
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nobody can guess things by magic: What custom plugin you are using and with what settings? What does it change from the normal behavior of WooCommerce?